# A linear map and a direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V,W$ be finitely dimensional, and $V_i, W_i$ be subspaces of $V,W$ respectively, $i \in \overline{1,3} = I$. Assume that $V = V_i \oplus V_j, W = W_i \oplus W_j$ for $i,j \in I, i \neq j$. Show that if $\dim W = \dim V$, then there exists an isomorphism $f\colon V \rightarrow W$ such that $$f(V_i) = W_i$$ for $i \in I$

I managed to state that

- $\dim W = 2n $
- $\dim V_i = \dim W_i = n$

But here I'm stuck. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Let $i \in I$. You have shown that $\dim V_i = \dim W_i \lt \infty$. I think you're actually done here. Define your isomorphism in the following way: Pick bases of $V_i$ and $W_i$. Because of dimension equality, map one basis to the other. Extend the bases to bases of $V$ resp. $W$ and map the remaining basis vectors.

Comment: But how can I then be sure that $f(V_2) = W_2$?

Comment: This has to be for all $i \in I$? Okay, this wasn't clear to me. Can you please clarify for me, what $\overline{1,3}$ means in this context, just to be sure? Thx!

Comment: $\overline{a,b} = \lbrace a, a+1, a+2, \dots, b \rbrace$